# Using Workday when start date is a wekeend date

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadhseet that pulls Planned Maintenace due dates. I am calculating 5 potential days the work can be scheduled, from 2 days before to days days after, so a range of 5 days. Unfortunately, sometimes the original due date is a weekend date(our business system calculates but doesn't append for weekend dates). So when I calculate the first 2 days, =workdate(A1,-2,holiday) and =workdate(A1,-1,holiday)it works fine, however for the 3rd date =workdate(A1,0,holiday) returns the original due date even if it's a weekend date.

Example, July 6th 2013 is a Saturday, so

```
1. workdate(A1,-2,holiday) = 7/3/2013
2. workdate(A1,-1,holiday) = 7/5/2013
3. workdate(A1,0,holiday)  = 7/6/2013  needs to be 7/8/2013
4. workdate(A1,1,holiday)  = 7/8/2013  needs to be 7/9/2013 
5. workdate(A1,2,holiday)  = 7/9/2013  needs to be 7/10/2013
```

Is there any way to compensate for a start date that is a weekend date!

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The function it appears you are using is workday(), not workdate()?  So what you probably need to do is put an adjustment on the # you pass to Workday if the day of the week is Sat/Sun.

```
=WORKDAY(A1,IF(OR(TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sat",TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sun"),1,0))
=WORKDAY(A1,IF(OR(TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sat",TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sun"),2,1))
=WORKDAY(A1,IF(OR(TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sat",TEXT(A1,"ddd") = "Sun"),3,2))
```

Comment: I did find one thing though after a more careful look, without the reference to the holiday list( holiday) it will not weed out holiday dates. So I need to get the "holiday" reference in there to handle those dates..... any thoughts?

Comment: Alan, I think I worked it out by doing this:

 =IF(WORKDAY($T474,IF(OR(TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sat",TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sun"),1,0)),WORKDAY($T474,1,holiday))
=IF(WORKDAY($T474,IF(OR(TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sat",TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sun"),1,0)),WORKDAY($T474,2,holiday))
=IF(WORKDAY($T474,IF(OR(TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sat",TEXT($T474,"ddd")="Sun"),1,0)),WORKDAY($T474,3,holiday))

Comment: Alan, the above formula I tried didn't work, but I did find a work around by identifying those due dates that fall on holidays and compensatyed for them using a different column in the worksheet. Thanks again for your initial help!